# Python: multiply 2 time series of matrices

Tags: pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-einsum

I have 2 time-series of matrices that I would like to multiply together. I have the data stored as a pandas MultiIndex frame. Both frames share the same first axis, which are *k* dates. So, the first matrix *A* has *k* dates, and for each date it has a *n* x *n* matrix, making it *k* x *n* x *n*. The second matrix *B* also has *k* dates and for each date it has an *n* by *m* matrix, making it *k* x *n* x *m*. For each date *k*, I would like to multiple the *n* x *n* part of *A* with the *n* x *m* part of *B*. I have changed my MultiIndex into a numpy array in a bid to speed up the operation as *k* is circa 15,000,000.
I have set this up as: `AB = np.array([np.dot(A.loc[date_], B.loc[date_]) for date_ in B.index.levels[0]])`. Unfortunately, this takes many, many hours to run. I have heard that using `np.einsum` is much, much quicker, but I have thusfar been unable to get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed this up and if possible, use `np.einsum` to achieve that same result in less time?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of both time-series and the expect output please?

Comment: It's not so much the `dot` that's slow but the `date_` and `loc` iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with einsum for hours, I finally managed to solve this: `np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl', A, B)`